# MYSQL Query - find multiple records that match a list of variables and return the max date for each one

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to craft a query to run against my "cdr" table where I can feed it about 200 phone #s and it would match it against the "src" column of the table and return the newest record based on the "calldate" column.

Example table:

```
+------------------+---------+-------------+
|     calldate     |   src   | disposition |
+------------------+---------+-------------+
| 10/23/2019 11:32 | 5551234 | ANSWERED    |
| 10/23/2019 11:32 | 5551245 | NO ANSWER   |
| 10/23/2019 11:28 | 5551234 | ANSWERED    |
| 10/23/2019 11:21 | 5551898 | ANSWERED    |
| 10/23/2019 11:20 | 5551245 | NO ANSWER   |
| 10/23/2019 11:20 | 5551887 | NO ANSWER   |
| 10/23/2019 11:18 | 5551898 | NO ANSWER   |
| 10/23/2019 11:18 | 5551887 | NO ANSWER   |
| 10/23/2019 11:17 | 5551234 | NO ANSWER   |
| 10/23/2019 11:14 | 5551898 | ANSWERED    |
| 10/23/2019 11:09 | 5551887 | ANSWERED    |
+------------------+---------+-------------+
```

So I need to be able to feed my sql query src #s since my database has a lot of records i dont really care about ie I only want to find the newest calls made by #s 5551234, 5551898 and 5551887 but ignore all others. I also need to make sure that disposition on the returned records are "ANSWERED" as well.

So what I tried so far without even filtering for answered or not was as follows:

```
SELECT src, calldate FROM cdr
WHERE src IN (5551234, 5551898, 5551887)
GROUP by src;
```

This does return 3 records but they dont seem to be the newest ones. For example 5551234 was from 11-18-2014 which is not the newest record. I confirmed this by just running the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM cdr WHERE calldate = (SELECT max(calldate) FROM cdr WHERE src LIKE '5551234');
```

the record returned was dated 06-24-2019.

Expecting the newest records to be returned, but it seems to be returning a random record (same one every time but it is neither the newest or oldest record available).

Trying to think of it logically I essentially need to pull max(calldate) for every IN entry I feed it vs pulling max calldate out of the returned records for the IN entries which results in just one record being returned. At wits end here and can't think straight.

Running this DB on mysql by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have part of the answer in your last query, I would do something like

```
SELECT src, MAX(calldate) AS last_call
FROM cdr
WHERE src IN (5551234, 5551898, 5551887)
-- AND disposition = 'ANSWERED'
GROUP by src;
```

Comment: Thanks! Any idea why adding the AS last_call makes it return the latest records vs how I had it before? More just wanting to know exactly what is going on.

Comment: Giving the result the alias "last_call" is just to make it easier for readability. Otherwise the result column name would be "MAX(calldate)". Normally, a query with the "MAX" or "MIN" or "COUNT" (for examples) will cause the query to only return one result, whichever meets the criteria. However, when we add the "GROUP BY" at the bottom, we're telling the query that we want the MAX for each DISTINCT GROUP BY element. Your first query was just grabbing the first calldate that would appear for each distinct src, but by adding the MAX keyword, it finds the max instead of the first one it finds.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a correlated subquery to filter on the last date per `src`. This approach avoids using aggregation and has usually better performance, especially with an index on `(src, calldate)`.

```
SELECT c.*
FROM cdr c
WHERE 
    c.src IN (5551234, 5551898, 5551887)
    AND calldate = (
        SELECT calldate
        FROM cdr c1
        WHERE c1.sr = c.src
        ORDER BY c1.calldate DESC
        LIMIT 1
    )
```

Another typical solution is to use window function `RANK()`:

```
SELECT calldate, src, disposition
FROM (
    SELECT c.*, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY src ORDER BY calldate DESC) rn
    FROM cdr c
    WHERE scr IN (5551234, 5551898, 5551887)
) x
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have just those three columns, then `group by` works.  Otherwise, I would recommend:

```
select c.*
from cdr c
where c.src in (5551234, 5551898, 5551887) and
      c.calldate = (select max(c2.calldate)
                    from cdr c2
                    where c2.src = c.src
                   );
```

For optimal performance, you want an index on `cd(src, calldate)`.  With such an index, I would expect this to be faster than a `group by` approach.